# PHP - remove HTML-attributes from string in JSON

Tags: php, json, attributes, replace

I have a JSON-response from embed.ly which I get in my PHP-script like this:

```
// jSON URL which should be requested
    $json_url = 'http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=hidden&url='.$_POST['url'];

    // Initializing curl
    $ch = curl_init( $json_url );

    // Configuring curl options
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
    );

    // Setting curl options
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    // Getting results
    $result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
```

My problem is that I want the responses from embed.ly embedded in my responsive layout, but embed.ly-responses of videos include with & height attributes:

```
{"provider_url": "http://www.youtube.com/", "description": "Markus Eisenrings Stromboli electric car on swiss television broadcast. See www.stromboli.ch for more information.", "title": "Stromboli Electric Car", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJCZnpHuFS8", "author_name": "hangflug", "height": 360, "thumbnail_width": 480, "width": 640, "html": "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/TJCZnpHuFS8?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", "author_url": "http://www.youtube.com/user/hangflug", "version": "1.0", "provider_name": "YouTube", "thumbnail_url": "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/TJCZnpHuFS8/hqdefault.jpg", "type": "video", "thumbnail_height": 360}
```

I tried removing all width & height-attributes from that JSON-string like this:

```
$result = json_encode(preg_replace('/\<(.*?)(width="(.*?)")(.*?)(height="(.*?)")(.*?)\>/i', '<$1$4$7>', json_decode($result)));
```

However, this is giving me a PHP-error.

```
Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projectname/ajax.php on line 22
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: sorry, added the errormessage above

Comment: I think stackoverflow removed something in the response, re-added it as code - see the iframe, it has width and height as attributes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do this:

```
$arr = json_decode($result, true); 
unset($arr["height"], $arr["width"]);
$result = json_encode($arr);
```

UPDATE:  For your specific example:

```
$arr = json_decode($result, true);
unset($arr["height"], $arr["width"]);
$arr_temp = explode(' ', $arr["html"]);
foreach ($arr_temp as $i => $val) {
    if ((substr($val, 0, 7) != "height=") && (substr($val, 0, 6) != "width="))
        $arr_html[] = $val;
}
$arr["html"] = implode(' ', $arr_html);
$json_result = json_encode($arr);
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/641e857da016ca3915bcefea480b59f401693044)

Comment: @RaphaelJeger - There was a mistake in the last line. `json_encode($result);` should have been `json_encode($arr);`

Comment: @RaphaelJeger I tested this and it does work. See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/641e857da016ca3915bcefea480b59f401693044

Answer (score 0):

finally got it to work with help form here like this:

```
$arr = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($arr as $key => & $val) {
    if($key=='html'){
        $html = preg_replace('/\<(.*?)(width="(.*?)")(.*?)(height="(.*?)")(.*?)\>/i','<$1$4$7>', $arr['html']);
        $arr[$key] = $html;
    }

}
$result = json_encode($arr);
```